# How to set the Altium PDF preview command line

Tags: altium

Using Altium 18.1

When outputting jobs, for example the schematic, Altium invokes the PDF reader. But it passes to the reader (Foxit Reader in my case) also some command line switch that Foxit Reader does not understand. So, instead of showing the PDF file, Foxit pops up a message explaining the acceptable command line switches. If I double click the generated file, it works flawlessly.

I searched everywhere in Altium, but I didn't find an option to set to correct this problem.

Comment: This link will take you, even without a valid license, to an excellent (and official) Altium forum: https://forum.live.altium.com (where all you need to do is register for an account).

Comment: Thank you @ChrisKnudsen, I'll take a look.